# Javascript game , facebook publish

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, publish

Ok , I've made a small javascript game and I want to publish it on facebook . Is there any good example how to do this step by step ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please visit https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appcenter/ complete guide to publish your java script/html5 Games for review on Facebook.com